# Windows 7 will not boot after sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

As the title says. My PC with windows 7 will not boot up correctly after going into sleep mode and failing to wake up.

From what I can tell this is a common problem with the motherboard ASUS P6T Deluxe. The harddrive in question is an Intel 70GB SSD.

Each time it attempts to boot the SSD, it immediatly jumps into Startup Repair but Startup Repair fails to fix the computer automatically.

I have updated to the latest BIOS. I've ran bootrec.exe /FixMBR and /FixBoot. I also ran a chkdsk that turned out ok.

Does anyone have any ideas of things I can try?

Comment: I know this will bring about a lot of hate, but all I can recommend is to stop using sleep mode, it isn't meant for desktops (and if you have an SSD boot time should be a non-issue, right?). Otherwise, if it's the motherboard's fault you'll probably need to update its firmware... be careful there.

Comment: @Thomas, are you confusing Sleep and Hibernate modes?  I use sleep on every desktop so I can get back to using it instantly.  Hibernate has lower power consumption so I use that on laptops.  But you're right that an SSD should make boot time negligable.

Comment: I found that I sometimes have trouble when I leave applications open.  I found that by closing all applications before putting the computer to sleep, it recovers prefectly every time.  Since it's the same Windows session, all of the applications I previously had open are cached by Windows and can be quickly started again.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food could be, if so I apologize. That said, if according to your experience, it is necessary to close all applications before going to sleep, then it sort of defeats the point (booting could actually end up being faster, excluding the boot overhead). I will try to reproduce the OP's issue right now (P67) and investigate.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on this board, and I also have an Intel SSD (120GB 330). Looks like a motherboard issue, @puttputt is your SSD controller in AHCI mode? Check in your BIOS.

Comment: In my experience, Hibernate is generally more reliable than Sleep.  I'm not sure which could really be said to be more for laptops than desktops, as both have benefits for each, but I prefer to stay away from Sleep - or, at least use Hybrid Sleep.

Comment: @Thomas, it does defeat the point a bit, but it's still a lot better than a five minute boot cycle.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Five minutes?!

Comment: Another option would be to check your BIOS suspend to ACPI state. Most motherboards have S1, S2 and S3 states. Toggle between these modes and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Does the computer boot correctly if you restart it or did the sleep mode cause it to complete not boot no matter what?